# How to enable fire and forget mode in moxi

Tags: memcached

I'm using `moxi` as a proxy for memcache cluster. In [documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/moxi-manual-1.8/#moxi-performance-tuning-standalone-moxi) I found that:

> it supports fire-and-forget work tasks.

So, "SET" should return `SUCCESS` immediately without waiting memcache response.

But I didn't find how to enable it! I tried to google, tried to read [source code](https://github.com/couchbase/moxi). It didn't help.

So, does anyone know how to enable this mode? Or is it enabled by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcached has quiet commands, but I don't think they are implemented very frequently by SDK's (except for use in multi-get/set operations). These are likely what you need to use in order to enable this behavior. It is not a moxi setting, but a set of client commands that you would use.

Binary quiet commands (They end with a Q for quiet)
https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/protocol_binary.h#L98